# how to run two process in parallel using multiprocessing module in python

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

My requirement is to capture logs for a particular http request sent to server from project server log file. So have written two function and trying to execute them parallel using multiprocessing module. **But only one is getting executed.** not sure what is going wrong.

My two functions - *run_remote_command* - using paramiko module for executing the tail command on remote server(linux box) and redirecting the output to a file. And *send_request* - using request module to make POST request from local system (windows laptop) to the server.

**Code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import paramiko
import datetime
import requests

def run_remote_command():
    basename = "sampletrace"
    suffixname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    filename = "_".join([basename, suffixname])
    print filename
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:                                              
        ssh.connect(hostname='x.x.x.x',username='xxxx',password='xxxx')
    except Exception as e:
        print "SSH Connecting to Host failed"
        print e
        ssh.close()
    print ssh
    tail = "tail -1cf /var/opt/logs/myprojectlogFile.txt >"
    cmdStr = tail + " " + filename 
    result = ''
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmdStr)
        print "error:" +str( stderr.readlines())
        print stdout
        #logger.info("return output : response=%s" %(self.resp_result))
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Run remote command failed cmd'
        print e
        ssh.close() 

def send_request():
    request_session = requests.Session()
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    data = "some data " 
    URL = "http://X.X.X.X:xxxx/request"
    request_session.headers.update(headers)
    resp = request_session.post(URL, data=data)
    print resp.status_code
    print resp.request.headers
    print resp.text

def runInParallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = mp.Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runInParallel(run_remote_command, send_request)
```

**Output:** only the function *send_request* is getting executed. Even I check the process list of the server there is no tail process is getting created

```
200
```

**Edited** the code per the @Ilja comment

Comment: You have a simple indentation error in your code. Move `p.start()` and `proc.append(p)`  back inside your `for fn in fns:` loop, and at least that part should work.

Comment: Thank you @IIja, have modified the script as per your suggestion, now both the function are getting called. But it is getting stuck at function run_remote_command. Script just does not come out from it